# Keyless entry on driver door only works when it rains

Tags: keyless-entry, cadillac, power-door-lock

On my 2006 Cadillac STS the driver door is keyless entry.

It works when it is raining, but at other times I have to insert the key into the lock.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is your specific question wondering what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes. I find it odd that it only works when it rains. I’m not sure if any sensors are getting wet and that is allowing it to work. I need it fixed and am not sure where to start.

Comment: My 2004 Ford Focus has had locking issues for 3-4 years. Sometimes the remote fob does not work, sometimes the physical key will not lock all doors (or even the driver's door). For what the car is worth, I live with it.